# Can't toggle touchpad with xinput after Ubuntu Update

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, synaptics, xinput

I have encountered a strange malfunction of my touchpad and xinput. After one the latest updates (timeframe 07/11/14 to 07/14/14) my touchpad stopped being toggleable when handled with xinput.

System:
Ubuntu 14.04, Kernel 3.13.0-33 
Lenovo Yoga 13 
TouchpadDevice: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad

Output of `xinput list`

```
    Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lenovo EasyCamera                         id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

What I did:
1) booted System --> touchpad works
2) Checked Properties of 
XInput with `xinput --watch-props 12`

```
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
Device Enabled (135):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (137): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
Device Accel Profile (268): 1
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (269):   2.500000
Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (270):   1.000000
Device Accel Velocity Scaling (271):    12.500000
Synaptics Edges (292):  1765, 5371, 1637, 4453
Synaptics Finger (293): 25, 30, 0
Synaptics Tap Time (294):   180
Synaptics Tap Move (295):   234
Synaptics Tap Durations (296):  180, 180, 100
Synaptics ClickPad (297):   1
Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (298):  0
Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (299):    282
Synaptics Two-Finger Width (300):   7
Synaptics Scrolling Distance (301): 106, 106
Synaptics Edge Scrolling (302): 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (303):   1, 1
Synaptics Move Speed (304): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.037601, 0.000000
Synaptics Off (305):    0
Synaptics Locked Drags (306):   0
Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (307):   5000
Synaptics Tap Action (308): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
Synaptics Click Action (309):   1, 3, 2
Synaptics Circular Scrolling (310): 0
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (311):    0.100000
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (312): 0
Synaptics Palm Detection (313): 0
Synaptics Palm Dimensions (314):    10, 200
Synaptics Coasting Speed (315): 20.000000, 50.000000
Synaptics Pressure Motion (316):    30, 160
Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (317): 1.000000, 1.000000
Synaptics Grab Event Device (318):  1
Synaptics Gestures (319):   1
Synaptics Capabilities (320):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
Synaptics Pad Resolution (321): 52, 42
Synaptics Area (322):   0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Soft Button Areas (323):  3568, 0, 4092, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Noise Cancellation (324): 8, 8
Device Product ID (255):    2, 7
Device Node (256):  "/dev/input/event4"
```

3) executed `xinput set-prop 12 "Device Enabled" 0` --> Touchpad stopped working
4) event updated under  `xinput --watch-props 12`

```
Property 'Device Enabled' changed.
Device Enabled (135):   0
Property 'Device Enabled' changed.
Device Enabled (135):   0
```

*Note: Event was reported twice... dunno why*
5) executed `xinput set-prop 12 "Device Enabled" 1`
6) event updated under `xinput --watch-props 12`

```
Property 'Device Enabled' changed.
Device Enabled (135):   1
```

BUT: Touchpad is not reacting or resuming his function in any way.
Complete re-run of `xinput --watch-props 12` produces

```
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
Device Enabled (135):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (137): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
Device Accel Profile (268): 1
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (269):   2.500000
Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (270):   1.000000
Device Accel Velocity Scaling (271):    12.500000
Synaptics Edges (292):  1765, 5371, 1637, 4453
Synaptics Finger (293): 25, 30, 0
Synaptics Tap Time (294):   180
Synaptics Tap Move (295):   234
Synaptics Tap Durations (296):  180, 180, 100
Synaptics ClickPad (297):   1
Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (298):  0
Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (299):    282
Synaptics Two-Finger Width (300):   7
Synaptics Scrolling Distance (301): 106, 106
Synaptics Edge Scrolling (302): 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (303):   1, 1
Synaptics Move Speed (304): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.037601, 0.000000
Synaptics Off (305):    0
Synaptics Locked Drags (306):   0
Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (307):   5000
Synaptics Tap Action (308): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
Synaptics Click Action (309):   1, 3, 2
Synaptics Circular Scrolling (310): 0
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (311):    0.100000
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (312): 0
Synaptics Palm Detection (313): 0
Synaptics Palm Dimensions (314):    10, 200
Synaptics Coasting Speed (315): 20.000000, 50.000000
Synaptics Pressure Motion (316):    30, 160
Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (317): 1.000000, 1.000000
Synaptics Grab Event Device (318):  1
Synaptics Gestures (319):   1
Synaptics Capabilities (320):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
Synaptics Pad Resolution (321): 52, 42
Synaptics Area (322):   0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Soft Button Areas (323):  3568, 0, 4092, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Noise Cancellation (324): 8, 8
Device Product ID (255):    2, 7
Device Node (256):  "/dev/input/event4"
```

A check with `xinput --test 12` is reporting no events at all.

So... long story short: The device has the same values like before.. BUT is not working any more.

I also checked `synclient -l` but the only important value "TouchpadOff" is set on "0"
I also disabled the "disable while typing"-option in gnome-control-center to avoid any interference.
AND I checked the enable-disable toggling with `synclient touchpadoff=0` and `synclient touchpadoff=1` which works flawless.
And finally I tried to toggle the touchpad with the neat little Button under "Mouse/Touchpad" in "gnome-control-center" that, as it creates the same events as I did, results in the same xiput events and outcome.

Question is: Is there any other value of any other application that is used/responsible for the on/off-toggling and .. if there is... how can I track it down?

Oh .. ah.. FYI: Touchpad resumes his work after relogging.

Thanks a lot for reading this far.. and in advance for your help an support.

Comment: Could you use `xinput disable <ID>` and `xinput enable <ID>` instead, or does that not solve it?

Comment: `xinput disable 12` and `xinput disable "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad` both create the same results... OFF-->hot, ON-->not. Both commands produce the same events like `xinput set-prop 12 "Device Enabled" 0`

Answer (score 1):

Publicado en:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2217808&page=2&p=13165714#post13165714

I buy a Logitech Keyboard Touchpad K400r (http://www.logitech.com/es-es/product/wireless-touch-keyboard-k400r). Working, but I alway use a command on the terminal with my laptop touchpad Dell Inspiron 1750:

`synclient LockedDrags=1`

but not working on logitech.

Now I do this:

`wachin@wachin-id:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:4024   id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_1.3M                    id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]`

I see that Logitech is pressent, now in this moment I am writing with them. Next I put on the terminal:

`wachin@wachin-id:~$ xinput list-props "Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:4024"
Device 'Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:4024':
    Device Enabled (133):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (135): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (265): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (266):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (267):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (268):    10.000000
    Device Product ID (252):    1133, 50475
    Device Node (253):  "/dev/input/event4"
    Evdev Axis Inversion (269): 0, 0
    Evdev Axes Swap (271):  0
    Axis Labels (272):  "Rel X" (143), "Rel Y" (144), "Rel Horiz Wheel" (262), "Rel Dial" (263), "Rel Vert Wheel" (264)
    Button Labels (273):    "Button Left" (136), "Button Middle" (137), "Button Right" (138), "Button Wheel Up" (139), "Button Wheel Down" (140), "Button Horiz Wheel Left" (141), "Button Horiz Wheel Right" (142), "Button Side" (257), "Button Extra" (258), "Button Forward" (259), "Button Back" (260), "Button Task" (261), "Button Unknown" (255), "Button Unknown" (255), "Button Unknown" (255), "Button Unknown" (255), "Button Unknown" (255), "Button Unknown" (255), "Button Unknown" (255), "Button Unknown" (255), "Button Unknown" (255), "Button Unknown" (255), "Button Unknown" (255), "Button Unknown" (255)
    Evdev Middle Button Emulation (274):    0
    Evdev Middle Button Timeout (275):  50
    Evdev Third Button Emulation (276): 0
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (277): 1000
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (278):  3
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (279):   20
    Evdev Wheel Emulation (280):    0
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (281):   0, 0, 4, 5
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (282):    10
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (283):    200
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (284): 4
    Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (285):  0`

I don't know the tipe of input for this device. Now I put on the terminal:

`xinput list-props "Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:4024" "Synaptics Locked Drags" 1`

and said this:

`wachin@wachin-id:~$ xinput list-props "Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:4024" "Synaptics Locked Drags" 1
Device 'Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:4024':
    Device Enabled (133):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (135): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (265): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (266):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (267):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (268):    10.000000
    Device Product ID (252):    1133, 50475
    Device Node (253):  "/dev/input/event4"
    Evdev Axis Inversion (269): 0, 0
    Evdev Axes Swap (271):  0
    Axis Labels (272):  "Rel X" (143), "Rel Y" (144), "Rel Horiz Wheel" (262), "Rel Dial" (263), "Rel Vert Wheel" (264)
    Button Labels (273):    "Button Left" (136), "Button Middle" (137), "Button Right" (138), "Button Wheel Up" (139), "Button Wheel Down" (140), "Button Horiz Wheel Left" (141), "Button Horiz Wheel Right" (142), "Button Side" (257), "Button Extra" (258), "Button Forward" (259), "Button Back" (260), "Button Task" (261), "Button Unknown" (255), "Button Unknown" (255), "Button Unknown" (255), "Button Unknown" (255), "Button Unknown" (255), "Button Unknown" (255), "Button Unknown" (255), "Button Unknown" (255), "Button Unknown" (255), "Button Unknown" (255), "Button Unknown" (255), "Button Unknown" (255)
    Evdev Middle Button Emulation (274):    0
    Evdev Middle Button Timeout (275):  50
    Evdev Third Button Emulation (276): 0
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (277): 1000
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (278):  3
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (279):   20
    Evdev Wheel Emulation (280):    0
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (281):   0, 0, 4, 5
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (282):    10
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (283):    200
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (284): 4
    Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (285):  0
unable to find device Synaptics Locked Drags
unable to find device 1`